# Animate CC - if Else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate-cc

I am currently trying to get a grasp of Adobe Animate CC, and how if Else -statement can be used with the tool. In this case, I would like to create a play/pause button. I could probably achieve this with JavaScript, but Animate CC doesn't tell me what are the ID's of the elements I create.

Right now, I have created an animation which plays automatically and loops, and with the button-click the animation stops. **What I would like to also achieve is, that 2nd click to the button would replay the animation**. Here is the code, maybe someone can help me to achieve this?

```js
this.Play_btn.addEventListener("click",playAnimation.bind(this));

function playAnimation() {
 this.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: "How can an If-Else statement be used to pause/rewind a clip?" then you would first need a condition to verify whether the "paused" property is true or false.  Once you know that you will know whether to play the clip from the beginning, or pause it.

```
function playAnimation() {
    if (this.paused) {
        this.gotoAndPlay(0);
    } else {
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

As for "How do I access my graphic IDs?" You set IDs when you give the MovieClip its instance name.  If the current timeline has an object called `Play_btn`, then `this.Play_btn` refers to the object as long as the script knows what `this` means.  You can also use `this["Play_btn"]` if you need to access it programmatically.

The `.bind(this)` statement allows `this` and `this.Play_btn` to work inside `playAnimation` the same way they would outside `playAnimation`.